# change default website language for google translation

Tags: html, greasemonkey, tampermonkey

I'm trying to change default language of website from "en" to "jp".

The webpage both contain english and japanesse.

I can't understand japanesse. But chrome translatation always suggest english translation (english to other language) first.

And I have to chage website language to japanesse to translation.

I think change website's default language can help.

I figure chrome extension like Tampermonkey can override attribute of html.

Here's my code.

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name default_lang
// @description change site language from en to jp
// @include         https://*siteaddress.com/*
// ==/UserScript==

document.body.innerHTML= document.body.innerHTML.replace(/xml:lang=\"en\" lang=\"en\"/g, "xml:lang=\"jp\" lang=\"jp\"");
```

Hope you could help me.

Answer (score 0):

html lang="en" should suffice. google-chrome will allways ask to translate it on Japanese if you are in Japan.

Comment: I want to translate japanesse to english. But everytime i click translate in chrome, I have to change website language.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
document.documentElement.setAttribute('lang', 'JP');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add this in your html :

```
<html lang="ja">
```

It will change the default langage to Japanese.